# Is there a way to attach ReactJs events to dynamically inserted HTML from Ajax JSON response?

Tags: json, ajax, reactjs, events

I have a react component with a button and div in it. This div would be populated with ajax response from server on clicking the button.

The server response is JSON format and one of JSON property contains string value with HTML content in it. This property value will be assigned to component state.

In the output, I saw raw HTML getting shown on the page. I managed to get that working with 'react-render-html' package.

Now I need to attach events to some of the HTML elements with certain class in them. With jQuery the .on('.classname') used to attach events to such elements. Is there a way, I can achieve the same using React. The event handler should be method inside the component.

Answer (score 1):

From the React documentation:

> **dangerouslySetInnerHTML**
>
> dangerouslySetInnerHTML is React’s replacement for using innerHTML in
>   the browser DOM. In general, setting HTML from code is risky because
>   it’s easy to inadvertently expose your users to a cross-site scripting
>   (XSS) attack. So, you can set HTML directly from React, but you have
>   to type out dangerouslySetInnerHTML and pass an object with a __html
>   key, to remind yourself that it’s dangerous. For example:
>
> ```
> function createMarkup() {
>   return {__html: 'First &middot; Second'};
> }
>
> function MyComponent() {
>   return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup()} />;
> }
> ```

So your API call would populate some component or application state, and you would then pass that as the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` prop on the element.

For the class specific handlers I'm not sure there is an elegant solution. This is very much starting to "smell" and if possible you should re-think your implementation of HTML in the database.

That said, you are still able to set event handlers on classes in native JavaScript without Jquery and you could do so here. What you have to be careful of is that if your application/component re-renders these event handlers would be removed. If you want to pursue this path you will need to carefully manage the HTML/event handlers to re-initialize themselves on a render, or manage the flow of rendering in such a way that they do not re-render except under conditions that you deem mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

Little late to answer but their is another way to get it done by using **"react-html-parser"**

```
import ReactHtmlParser from 'react-html-parser' ;
<p>ReactHtmlParser("<h2>Hello world</h2>")</p>
```

This is better approach to parse html string to React element.